# How to import airflow connections from a json file

Tags: docker, connection, airflow

I have established two connections `aws_default` and `google_cloud_default` in a json file like so:

```json
{
    "aws_default": {
        "conn_type": "s3",
        "host": null,
        "login": "sample_login",
        "password": "sample_secret_key",
        "schema": null,
        "port": null,
        "extra": null
      },
    "google_cloud_default": {
          "conn_type": "google_cloud_platform",
          "project_id": "sample-proj-id123",
          "keyfile_path": null,
          "keyfile_json": {sample_json},
          "scopes": "sample_scope",
          "number_of_retries": 5,
        } 
}
```

I have a local airflow server containerized in docker. What I am trying to do, is to import the connections from this file, that way I don't need to define the connections in the Airflow UI.

I have an entrypoint.sh file which runs everytime the airflow image is built.

I have included this line `airflow connections import connections.json` in that shell file.

in my docker-compse.yaml file, I have added a binded a volume like so:

```
- type: bind
source: ${HOME}/connections.json
target: /usr/local/airflow/connections.json
```

However, when I run my DAG locally, which includes hooks that connect to these connections, I receive errors: i.e.

```
The conn_id `google_cloud_default` isn't defined
```

So I'm not too sure how to proceed. I was reading about Airflow's local filesystem secrets backend [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/local-filesystem-secrets-backend.html#storing-and-retrieving-connections).

And it mentions this code chunk to establish the file path:

```
[secrets]
backend = airflow.secrets.local_filesystem.LocalFilesystemBackend
backend_kwargs = {"variables_file_path": "/files/var.json", "connections_file_path": "/files/conn.json"}
```

But, as I check my airflow.cfg, I can't find this code chunk. Am I supposed to add this to airflow.cfg?

Comment: `I have an entrypoint.sh file which runs everytime the airflow image is built.
I have included this line airflow connections import connections.json in that shell file.`

Are you running entrypoint when your image is building or starting? You should run that command when you start that container in docker-compose you can define entrypoint or you can define the `ENTRYPOINT` layer in your `Dockerfile` Your config file is not available when you are building the image as you're mouting it during the start.

Comment: Sorry, I may be mistaken. That file is indeed running when starting the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should add a section [secrets] in your airflow.cfg. Don't forget to also copy the files to the container in your docker-compose.yaml :

```
volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/files
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

Note that the connections won't appear in the GUI but you can use them from code.